# Where to get IE Hot fix for 11.0.9600.17207

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am using IE 11 (11.0.9600.17207), where most of the functionality working fine.

But When i am using IE 11 (11.0.9600.17127) , some functions are not working fine.

So from where i can get fix or patch for IE 11 to upgrade it to (11.0.9600.17207).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try Windows Update?

Comment: Well my client doesn't want to upgrade Windows

Comment: Why would they install a hotfix, if they're not prepared to install updates?

Comment: Actually I have the same problem. I.e. cannot receive files throught .NET `Response.TransmitFile()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove windows update, 'KB2962872'.
It will upgrade mshtml.dll from version 11.0.9600.172126 to 11.0.9600.17207.

Reference: https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?217555-ISDEV-Crashing